iOS 17 Map Initial Zoom Level
I’m working on a SwiftUI app that displays a map with multiple markers and polylines between them. I want the map to start zoomed out to show a 500 km high/over of the starting point. However, the map is not zooming out to the initial region as expected.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
struct PutMarkersMapView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<PlacemarkData> {$0.destination == nil}) private var searchPlacemarks: [PlacemarkData]
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    @State private var selectedResults: [MKMapItem] = []
    @State private var routes: [MKRoute] = []
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init() {
        let initialSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00075, longitudeDelta: 0.00075)
        let initialCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.8365780, longitude: 14.3068966)
        _region = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(center: initialCenter, span: initialSpan))
    }
    
    private let startingPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 40.8365772,
        longitude: 14.3068966
    )
    
    private func randomColor() -> Color {
        let color = Color(
            red: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            green: Double.random(in: 0...1),
            blue: Double.random(in: 0...1)
        )
        return color
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        MapReader { proxy in
            Map(selection: $selectedResult) {
                Marker("Start", coordinate: self.startingPoint)
                ForEach(selectedResults, id: \.self) { item in
                    Marker("", coordinate: item.placemark.coordinate)
                        .tint(randomColor())
                }
                
                ForEach(routes, id: \.self) { route in
                    MapPolyline(route.polyline)
                        .stroke(randomColor(), lineWidth: 3)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedResult){
                getDirections()
            }
            .onTapGesture { position in
                if let coordinate = proxy.convert(position, from: .local) {
                    let mtPlacemark = PlacemarkData(
                        name: "",
                        address: "",
                        latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                        longitude: coordinate.longitude
                    )
                    modelContext.insert(mtPlacemark)
                    let newResult = MKMapItem(
                        placemark: MKPlacemark(
                            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                                latitude: mtPlacemark.latitude,
                                longitude: mtPlacemark.longitude
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    selectedResults.append(newResult)
                    getDirections()
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedResults) { _ ,_ in
                getDirections()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getDirections() {
        routes.removeAll()
        
        for result in 0..<selectedResults.count {
            let request = MKDirections.Request()
            request.source = result == 0 ? MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation() : selectedResults[result - 1]
            request.destination = selectedResults[result]
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            directions.calculate { response, error in
                guard let route = response?.routes.first else { return }
                routes.append(route)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Model
class PlacemarkData {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var destination: Destination?
    
    init(name: String, address: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        .init(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}

@Model
class Destination {
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?
    var latitudeDelta: Double?
    var longitudeDelta: Double?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var placemarks: [PlacemarkData] = []
    
    init(name: String, latitude: Double? = nil, longitude: Double? = nil, latitudeDelta: Double? = nil, longitudeDelta: Double? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitudeDelta = latitudeDelta
        self.longitudeDelta = longitudeDelta
    }
    
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion? {
        if let latitude, let longitude, let latitudeDelta, let longitudeDelta {
            return MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta)
            )
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

I’ve set the initial span of the MKCoordinateRegion to what I believe should show a 500 km view, but when I run the app, the map starts zoomed in on the starting point instead of zoomed out.
What I’ve tried:
Adjusting the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta values of the MKCoordinateSpan.
Ensuring that the region state variable is being updated correctly.
Expected behavior:
The map should start with a 500 km view over away.
Actual behavior:
The map starts zoomed in on the starting point without showing the wider 500 km view.
Can anyone help me understand why the map is not starting with the zoomed-out view and how to achieve the desired flyover effect?
